# xlsx file unprotected when transfer to Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, xlsx

I create a `*.xlsx` file using Microsoft Office, Then protected and hide the sheet,

but when I upload to the google drive and open it.

The sheet will be unprotected and visibled. Is there any way to solve theme.

Comment: Your problem is better suited to SuperUser as it isn't a programming issue. I tried to reproduce it anyway and couldn't, so you might want to include a set of steps.

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are two different products. Why do you assume that the features of Excel work in Google Drive? Why should they? The two companies don't work together to make that happen.  There is a modicum of shared functionality, because Google copied a lot of stuff from Excel. But not all Excel functionality exists in Google sheets. If you want to use Excel, use Excel and use Microsoft technology for cloud and sharing. If you want to use Google Sheets, use Google sheets and Google technology for cloud and sharing. Don't expect miracles if you mix the two.